# download from my website by ip and cloudflare not working - php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, download, ip, cloudflare

I have website that allow users to download movies .. i have function that use user ip to check if user download from my website or get direct download without enter my website and use it to complete download

**My problem is when i protect my website with cloudflare i have problem because cloudflare change user ip 
and check process return fail all time**

Are there any operation to solve this problem ? 
Are there another operation to check download without user ip ??

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [install something to restore the visitor IP](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200038166-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-to-my-server-logs-).

Since CloudFlare acts as a reverse proxy for websites, our IPs will show until you install something to restore the visitor IP.